# php converting date to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssTZD

Tags: php, date, xml-sitemap

I am tring to make the google news sitemap by php script from mysql.(all the date save as  timestamp in +08:00)

But how to converting date to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssTZD?

For example `1338048000` => `2012-05-26T09:00:00+08:00`

```
echo date("Y-m-d T h:i:s",'1338048000').'+08:00';//2012-05-26 PDT 09:00:00+08:00
```

Not the result what I need. And how to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo date("c",'1338048000');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', '1338048000');
```

The `T` means something, and needs to be escaped. Or, since PHP5, the ISO8601 date format is natively supported with the `c` character.

Additionally, using `gmdate` instead of `date` removes the need to worry about timezones.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("c", "1338048000").'+08:00';
```